# Solving $x f'(x) - f'(x)f(x) + \alpha x^{\alpha - 1} = 0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been trying to solve the differential equation
$$x f'(x) - f'(x)f(x) + \alpha x^{\alpha - 1} = 0 $$
where $\alpha > 0$ is a fixed parameter, $f(0) = 0$ is the boundary condition, and the domain is $\mathbb{R}^+$.

In case of $\alpha = 1$, Wolfram Alpha suggests that
$$ f(x) = W(-e^{-x- 1}) + x+ 1$$
where $W$ is the product log function. However, Wolfram Alpha won't give me a solution for the general case. Is it possible to get a 'nice' expression for $f$ here? If not, can one still gain some qualitative insight into its properties?

Comment: It seems very difficult to establish the existence of any solutions for me, and moreover the result for the case $\alpha=1$ case also seems weird to me; if we suppose that the derivative is bounded near $0$, then as $x \rightarrow 0$ we will get nonsense; so what is the domain you are considering?

Comment: @RohanDidmishe Apologies for not stating this originally: the domain is $x \geq 0$. If I am not mistaken, the $\alpha = 1$ solution implies that $f(0) = 0$ as desired.

Comment: The DE can be written as
$$u'+u^{1/\alpha}=f$$
where $u(f)=x^{\alpha}(f)$.

Comment: The solution for the $\alpha=2$ case is
$$f=xy$$
where
$$(y+1)^3(y-2)^4=Cx(y-1)$$
Since $f(0)=0$ regardless of the $C$ value, we can set $C=0$ to get the trivial solutions $f=-x,2x$. To get the other solutions, one would have to solve a polynomial equation of degree $7$ which is impossible to solve in the general case using radicals. However, I am trying to work on a series expansion for $y$ using Lagrange's inversion theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is too long for a comment] For $\alpha=1/2$ the equation can be transformed to an Airy equation,
\begin{align}
(x-f)f'+\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}=0,\quad
\frac{x'_f}{2\sqrt x}+x=f,\\\\
u''_{ff}=fu,\quad\text{where}\quad x=\left(\frac{u'_f}{u}\right)^2,
\end{align}
which has the solution
\begin{align}
u=C_1 \mathrm{Ai}(f)+C_2\mathrm{Bi}(f),
\end{align}
so then
\begin{align}
x=\left(\frac{\mathrm{Ai}'(f)+C\mathrm{Bi}'(f)}{\mathrm{Ai}(f)+C\mathrm{Bi}(f)}\right)^2.
\end{align}
From the initial condition $f(0)=0$ we find that
\begin{align}
C=-\frac{\mathrm{Ai}'(0)}{\mathrm{Bi}'(0)}=3^{-1/2},
\end{align}
and so our solution is
\begin{align}
x=\left(\frac{\sqrt 3\mathrm{Ai}'(f)+\mathrm{Bi}'(f)}{\sqrt 3\mathrm{Ai}(f)+\mathrm{Bi}(f)}\right)^2.
\end{align}
The general case is an Abel equation of the form $yy'-y=x^n$, to which I'm not aware of a general solution.